# Angular: How to send object through $http.get?

Tags: angularjs, http-get

customerLogin is object that I want to send to my service. 
I do not want to use query string and do not want parameters separately.
Below is the code:

```
var config = {
  customerLogin : {  // object I intend to send
    'EmailID': $scope.existingCustomer.email,
    'PhoneNumber': $scope.existingCustomer.phoneNumber,
    'Passkey': $scope.existingCustomer.password
  }
}
$http.get(existingCustomerUrlConstant, config).
```

In webapi, i have below code:

```
 [HttpGet]
 // customerLogin object i want to receive here
 public CustomerLogin GetCustomer(CustomerLogin customerLogin)
 {
     GetCustomerDAL getCustomerDAL = new GetCustomerDAL(customerLogin);
     return customerLogin;
 }
```

customerLogin is null here.
How can i receive object here from Angular service call?

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to user POST method instead?

Comment: If you want to send additional data with an `HTTP GET` you must use the query string or something in the URL itself.  That's just the way that GET works. If you don't want any data in the URL, then you have to use POST, PATCH, PUT, etc...

Comment: @ZdenekHatak: Since I was getting the data, I thought of using GET. With POST, it works fine. I thought it would be good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using POST method is the right call. As I stated in the comment.

Comment: I have a question. If I need to use POST when I need to send object, then when would I use http.get, http.delete, http.put etc? Let me know here or share a link. Please.

Comment: $HTTP.GET is for generally for simple getting stuff from an URL. DELETE for deleting stuff - e.g, in frontend of admin you send $http.delete to delete an article and the backend has to listen to the delete method and process the delete in the database. PUT is for updating things. Read more about REST.